# Deploy on multiple servers using Subversion as SVN

Tags: mysql, svn, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've a job on my hands that I don't know how to accomplish it.

We've two EC2 instances running on Amazon, the development one and the production; each one with its own MySQL database. Also, we've a third one only with the Subversion SVN.

Currently, the deploys are done through SFTP using Filezilla, from the local machine of one of the developers to the server; where he has to copy all files by hand to the machine.

So, it's very difficult to ensure that both servers have the same code version.

I think that the solution passes by having two SVN, one on the Development Server and one on the Production one. The Dev one would have all the commits on the 'Trunk' folder. Each 'Branch' that would be marked has a release, would pass to the Production SVN.

I think that the deploys would be by far more easy, only having to checkout.

Since I'm a newbie on doing this kind of configurations, how can I accomplish this? Configuring the SVN on both machines, and pass each Branch to production?
The EC2 instances are running on Debian, with Nginx and Supervisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a dedicated server for SVN, you may try installing and configuring [**JENKINS**](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on that machine, and on jenkins you can create multiple jobs(deployment task), for making the deployment to different EC2 instances.

Jenkins is an application that monitors executions of repeated jobs, such as building a software project or jobs run by cron.

We are using Jenkins for remote deployments, which are scheduled based on the time and also based on SVN commits.

Tip : Try doing a setup of jenkins on your local machine, and see how to make a deployment to another local machine.

Comment: You can also search for other "Continuous integration tools"

Comment: Do you know any tutorials where I can see the configurations step by step? Thanks!